# How to merge rows of two dataframe with unequal columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

Column names of df1 are:
`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`

Column names of df2 are:
`col1`,`col2`,`col3`

Shape of df1` is 40000 rows and 7 columns

shape of df2 is 7000 rows and 3 columns.

I want to merge `df1` and `df2`, and create `df3` with whoes shape should be `47000 rows and 7 columns`.

Since the columns of `df2` are just 3, when we merge them other columns should be null

Comment: please provide data samples to replicate

Comment: @anky_91 This one time I think the question is clear enough.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen may be , however i have seen instances where the statement differs the input v/s expected output. Seeing the input v/s expected always helps to be precise .(IMO) :)

Comment: @anky_91 Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#ignoring-indexes-on-the-concatenation-axis

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of the word `merge` may be causing you confusion when you do searches for this problem. `merge` in pandas is like a `join` in SQL.

What you really want to do is `append` one dataframe to another. Like this:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list('CD'))
df3 = df1.append(df2)
print(df3)
    A   B   C   D
0   0.756090    0.870448    1.620658    0.292611
1   -0.123287   -1.310157   -1.543878   1.248768
2   -1.008736   0.718931    0.292012    -2.258360
3   1.209176    -0.577204   -0.529350   0.495382
0   NaN NaN 0.180752    -2.143169
1   NaN NaN 1.515064    2.005604
2   NaN NaN -0.507997   0.129836
3   NaN NaN 0.145295    -0.047879
```